# Fetching data from multiple database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework-4.1, multiple-databases

I have multiple databases say DB1, DB2, DB3 and MembershipDB.
Every Database has GUID column named ApplicationID & set of Users having MembershipID as GUID.
Each User of every Database is Isolated (have no relationship) with User of other Database.
Membership Database contains the Users MembershipID and Database’s ApplicationID , password, username, email etc.

I need to create a common login system like When a user provides his login credential authentication is to be done from MembershipDB and his data is to be fetched from the database he is registered to.
Eg: a user from DB1 provides his login details, authentication is done from membershipDB. Now rest of his data is to be fetched from DB1(as he is registered to DB1) to his dashboard. I am bit confuse how to build this login system. 
Authentication part is no problem. But how to connect to the correct DB to get the correct data for the user. 
All the valuable comments and suggestions are welcome.

I am using Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008, Entity Framework 4.2 (database ist approach), WCF, asp.net MVC 4

Answer (score 0):

in member ship DB,  you should have a column that record which database this use will go to
for example:
id, username,password, applicationid, email, DBName

```
select * from membershipdb where username='user1', and password = 'password1'.
//Code to fetch the database
//rs = recordset
//This assume these two database in same server
String DB = rs.getString(6) // 6 is DBName

DBobj->executeQuery("USE "+DB);
DBobj->executeSelect("select * from DB1.Table1 where Column1 = 'column1'");
```

//if the Database are in different servers, you can connect to server 2 and assign to  DBobj2 
//Then use the similar method as above

Comment: Thanks Michael,but consider this scenario initially there are following database db1 db2 and membershipdb after a month or so there will be 4 more db. so it will be difficult to follow your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly then you need to connect to different databases dynamically without modifying your code. 
Lets assume you have 2 customers Customer1 and Customer2. You created 2 databases with names Database_Customer1 and Database_Customer2 for these customers.

Map entity framework with any of the Customer's database with name 'CustomerDbSpecificEntities'.

Now you need to add following connection strings in your .config file.

```
<add name="Database_Customer1_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomerDbSpecific.csdl|res://*/CustomerDbSpecific.ssdl|res://*/CustomerDbSpecific.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Customer1ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseCustomer1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="Database_Customer2_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomerDbSpecific.csdl|res://*/CustomerDbSpecific.ssdl|res://*/CustomerDbSpecific.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Customer2ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseCustomer2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In your code in Data Access Layer,

```
String ConnectionStringName = MembershipDBProvider.GetConnectionStringNameForCustomer(CustomerName);
using (CustomerDbSpecificEntities context = new CustomerDbSpecificEntities("Name=" + ConnectionStringName))
    {
        //use context here
    }
```

Create a table (CustomerDbConnection) in common database (membership database) to store mapping of Customer Name and its database connection string name.

'GetConnectionStringNameForCustomer(CustomerName)' searches in CustomerDbConnection table and returns the connection string name for given customer. Which is used to established the connection to customer specific database.

Now if you have new customer in future then you have to make following changes,
1. Add new row in CustomerDbConnection.
2. Add new connection string in .config file

Please let me know if you need more detailed about it.

Comment: Hello Arvind! Thanks for the suggestion. Would you please elaborate your suggestion !

Comment: This solution assumes that all of your customer's specific databases use same schema. So you would create entity framework mapping just once and by passing different connection string you can connect to customer specific database. If you still need more explanation then we can chat.

Comment: its better v can chat ! gopalchettri@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Coddey! I hope your problem is resolved after our discussion. I expect you to post your solution here to help others who are facing same issues.